# Load method of XslCompiledTransform class throws StackOverflow Exception

Tags: c#, .net, xslt

I'm trying to build our company's project and Load method of

> XslCompiledTransform throws StackOverflow Exception

and it bugs me because literally five minutes ago I was able to build and right now with no changes of the templates or code it started to `throw exceptions`...

```
if (context.Request.IsLocal)
{
    var cc = new XslCompiledTransform();
    using (var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(context.Server.MapPath("/templates/xhtmlmain.xsl"))
        { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse })
    {
        cc.Load(xmlReader);
    }
    return cc;
}
```

Comment: See whether https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/xmlteam/2011/09/26/effective-xml-part-5-something-went-really-wrong-outofmemoryexception-and-stackoverflowexception-thrown-when-using-xslcompiledtransform/ helps solving it.

Comment: Thanks man, that actually helped. Turns out in my case I had to make thread with larger than default stack size due to our poorly written templates which are unable to be refactored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out in my case I had to make thread with larger than default stack size due to our poorly written templates which are unable to be refactored.

This is the code:

```
 private static XslCompiledTransform LoadTransformations(HttpContext context, XslCompiledTransform cc)
    {

        using (var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(context.Server.MapPath("/templates/xhtmlmain.xsl"))
        {
            DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse
        })
        {
            cc.Load(xmlReader);
        }
        return cc;
    }

    private static XslCompiledTransform CreateTransformation(HttpContext context)
    {
        var cc = new XslCompiledTransform();

        // Since our templates are most likely poorly written it takes
        // unusual amount of memory for a thread to handle the transformation
        // leaving the application throwing StackOverflow Exception.

        // This code creates different thread with 8MB stack size which actually succeeds in
        // transforming all the templates.

        // Creates custom thread and start it.  
        Thread t = new Thread(() => cc = GTHttpHandler.LoadTransformations(context, cc), 8 * 1024 * 1024);
        t.Start();

        // Ensure our transformation thread is finished before doing anything.
        t.Join();

        return cc;
    }
```